# What happens if I merge a commit that has removed code my new feature depends on

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Say Alice and I have cloned a repository and been making changes. Alice commits her changes and pushes to remote. I then fetch that change and merge it with mine. Imagine Alice, in her latest commit, has removed a class called Vehicle. I in my turn, I have added a new class called Car that extends the Vehicle class. Now, when I merge her commit into mine, there's obviously going to be a problem. 
 Does this mean  that I have to examine the code and test it before merging? (Probably yes). What is the common practice in this situation?

Comment: Note that the `Vehicle` class may not be removed after the merge if your version of the story is what gets retained.  But assuming `Vehicle` _does_ get removed, then yes, you would have a problem.  The solution to this is for you and Alice to communicate with each other during the development process.  If it gets to the point where you need Git to make design decisions for you, I would consider it as already being too late.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, "Note that the Vehicle class may not be removed after the merge if your version of the story is what gets retained." But change is not always about adding. It's sometimes about removing the unnecessary, isn't it? How does Git decide whether the Vehicle class is needed or redundant?

Comment: I actually don't know the exact rules which Git uses, but I have seen it go both way, i.e. I have seen `Vehicle` being removed and also being retained.  My point was simply that you should not be relying on Git to make software design decisions like this.  Just talk to Alice.

Comment: Ok, I will :)  Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to leave this open as others will give their opinions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that I have to examine the code and test it before merging? (Probably yes).

You should examine the code *after the merge*.
You *could* examine the other developer's branch before merging,
but that would be less convenient.

> What is the common practice in this situation?

After a merge, you should rebuild the project and rerun all tests.
If a class you depend on is removed during the merge,
you will get a compilation error in a compiled language.
In interpreted languages hopefully you have test cases covering the affected code, so the problem will become apparent when you rerun automated tests.
When you detect a problem, you can inspect what was merged,
and possibly discuss with the other developers any questions you may have about the reason for the changes.

Hopefully in a team with good communication and good separation of tasks,
there should be no such logical conflicts in implementation changes.